# Wifi doesn't work: interface not powered

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, network, wifi

Since yesterday I don't see any wifi network after turning it on:

[image]

That's the error I get from the console.

[image]

Does it mean it is a hardware problem?

It's a Mavericks install (10.9.2), build 13C64 in a MBP 15-inch, Mid 2012.

Comment: What it actually shows is your WiFi and Network settings are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly it does show Connected but the WiFi settings are wrong and the Network settings are wrong?

Anyway, lets bypass the GUI and use Terminal for some direct commands.

In Terminal type (to turn it on)

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Next type (to scan)

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

Finally type (to connect)

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```